# Sqlalchemy mock : UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock : suppress add/commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Could someone help me with

1. implement mock calls to add and commit
2. or tell UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock to ignore calls to add/commit

```
self.session = UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock(data=[
    (
        [mock.call.query(MyType),
         mock.call.filter(MyType.source == 'something')],
        [instance_of_my_type]
    )
```